# Jenkins agent configuration

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I'm running Jenkins on ECS cluster. I have controller and agent in two different ECS cluster. I'm using ECS plugin to launch the agents. I'm running the agents using Jenkins agent. I have configured agents using jenkins/inbound-agent:jdk11 image from the docker hub. But i have one issue while running the agents. I have to run agents as root user instead of Jenkins user, with Jenkins user docker and other apt commands are not working. I'm using Jenkins 2.401.1 version. I need to run container using Jenkins user without any issue. Can someone please help me?